# Tkinter button autoclick

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, tkinter

I am trying to code a simple app that generates buttons automatically and by clicking on the generated buttons save their value into a table of a db. For some reason I dont understand when generating the buttons it is as if they autoclick saving all the values. Can anyone tell me why?

```
try:
    conexion=sqlite3.connect('libreria.db')
    cursor=conexion.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM categoria")
    cate=cursor.fetchall()
except sqlite3.OperationalError:
    print("Error: No hay datos que mostrar")
else:
    eleccion=lambda x: cursor.execute("INSERT INTO pedido VALUES(null,{})".format(x))
    for c in cate:
        print("\n*",c[1],"*")
        ttk.Label(marcoprincipal,text="*{}*".format(c[1])).pack(fill="both",expand=1)
        libros=cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM libro WHERE categoria_id={}".format(c[0])).fetchall()
        for l in libros:
            print("\t",l[1])
            ttk.Button(marcoprincipal,text="{}".format(l[1]),command=eleccion(l[0])).pack()
            conexion.commit()


    conexion.commit()
    conexion.close()
```

Comment: You are on the internation version of Stackoverflow. Please write in English here, or you can use Spanish version of the site (Estás en la versión internacional de Stackoverflow. Por favor escriba aquí en inglés, o puede usar la versión en español del sitio) - https://es.stackoverflow.com/.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs to es.stackoverflow.com

Comment: Ok, I'im sorry. I'm a new user and i didnt know. Im rewriting my question.